# InvokeMember is very slow, anyway to avoid this?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, reflection, late-binding

I have to do reflection and late binding so i don't know if there is a way to speed things up.
 Thought I would give it a shot.

This snippet takes about 15 seconds to complete which is way too slow, but seeing how I need to read the metadata.

```
private static object InvokeCall(Type HostObjectType, Object HostObject, CallType callType, string PropertyOrMethodName, object[] args)
{
    if (callType == CallType.Method)
    {
        return MyObjectType.InvokeMember(PropertyOrMethodName,System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, myObject, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: A *single* call to InvokeMember will absolutely *not* cost 15 seconds for the reflection overhead.  Are you invoking `InvokeCall` repeatedly?  Otherwise, by far the most likely explanation is that whatever method you are actually invoking is taking a while and you should investigate the problem over there.

Comment: How slow does this particular method perform when early binding?

Comment: @Kirk ah yes, it is calling a rather large method afterwards, though it won't let me step in, I will look into that a little more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that 15s is when used in a loop; reflection isn't *that* slow.

You can speed up reflection (and invoke in particular) by obtaining the MethodInfo and using Delegate.CreateDelegate *once*. You then cache and re-use the resulting **typed** delegate (matching the expected call signature). Then use the typed delegate Invoke.

Note untyped delegate invoke is slow; it must be typed. Also; you can be sneaky and use a delegate with an extra (leading) parameter to invoke an *instance* method against a range of different objects, if you need the target object to change per-call.

For more complex scenarios, Expression or DynamicMethod are useful.

Comment: By typed delegate, do you mean, e.g., casting the delegate to `Func<int, int, int>` if the method takes two `int`s and returns their sum?

Comment: @JonSagara yes, although if possible: "function pointers" (which weren't readily available when I wrote this) would be even better

Answer (score 5):

Take a look to [Fasterflect - A Fast and Simple Reflection API](https://github.com/buunguyen/fasterflect/) and [Fast Invoker](http://fastinvoker.codeplex.com/) they are ready to use solutions and interesting to study.

If you want to go by your own way check articles: [Dodge Common Performance Pitfalls to Craft Speedy Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx) and [Dynamically Compiled Lambdas vs. Pure Reflection](http://www.justnbusiness.com/post/2009/09/01/Dynamically-Compiled-Lambdas-vs-Pure-Reflection.aspx)

Comment: Fasterflect migrated to https://github.com/buunguyen/fasterflect

Answer (score 1):

Try using an expression tree compiled lambda and cache the lambda. I've leveraged this extensively with great success.

http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/fast-late-bound-invocation-with-expression-trees/